# What's the command to defrag XFS?

Tags: command-line, cron, defrag, xfs

I have a /home partition in a separate disk with XFS, how do I de-fragment it ? (on-line or off-line)

I haven't tried anything yet and the / partition has BTRFS. Also how to schedule it would be nice. But I can check that out in already responded questions.

This was the output :

```
sudo xfs_db -c frag -r /dev/sdb5
actual 329394, ideal 301436, fragmentation factor 8.49%
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XFS provides a filesystem defragmentation utility, `xfs_fsr` that can defragment the files on a mounted and active XFS filesystem.

It can be useful to view XFS fragmentation periodically.

`xfs_fsr` improves the organization of mounted filesystems. The reorganization algorithm operates on one file at a time, compacting or otherwise improving the layout of the file extents.
Inspect fragmentation levels

To see how much fragmentation your file system currently has:

```
sudo xfs_db -c frag -r /dev/sd??
```

To begin defragmentation, use the `xfs_fsr` command which is included with the `xfsprogs` package.

```
sudo xfs_fsr /dev/sd??
```

Change **??** to what corresponds your partition

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325469&p=13493414#post13493414